# Using list.count to sort a list in-place using .sort() does not work. Why?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list by frequency of its elements.

```
>>> a = [5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2]
>>> a.sort(key = a.count)
>>> a
[5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2]
```

`a` is unchanged. However:

```
>>> sorted(a, key = a.count)
[1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4]
```

Why does this method not work for `.sort()`?

Comment: Aside from the fact that accessing the list while you're mutating it results in unpredictable behavior, you should not use the `count` method as a key function in the first place, since it unnecessarily increases the average time complexity of the task from *O(n log n)* to *O(n ^ 2 x log n)*. Instead, use `collections.Counter` first to create a mapping of each distinct item to its count, and use the `get` method of the mapping dict as a key function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you see is the result of a certain **CPython implementation detail** of `list.sort`. Try this again, but create a copy of `a` first:

```
a.sort(key=a.copy().count)
a
# [1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4]
```

**`.sort` modifies `a` internally, so `a.count` is going to produce un-predictable results.** This is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) as an implementation detail.

What `copy` call does is it creates a copy of `a` and uses *that* list's `count` method as the key.  You can see what happens with some debug statements:

```
def count(x):
    print(a)
    return a.count(x)

a.sort(key=count)
[]
[]
[]
...
```

`a` turns up as an empty list when accessed inside `.sort`, and `[].count(anything)` will be `0`. This explains why the output is the same as the input - the predicates are all the same (`0`).

OTOH, `sorted` creates a new list, so it doesn't have this problem.

---

If you really want to sort by frequency counts, the idiomatic method is to use a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

a.sort(key=Counter(a).get)
a
# [1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4]
```

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't work with the `list.sort` method because CPython decides to "empty the list" temporarily (the [other answer already presents this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56695146/5393381)). This is mentioned in the [documentation as implementation detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

> **CPython implementation detail**: While a list is being sorted, the effect of attempting to mutate, or even inspect, the list is undefined. The C implementation of Python makes the list appear empty for the duration, and raises `ValueError` if it can detect that the list has been mutated during a sort.

The [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Objects/listobject.c#L2171-L2175) contains a similar comment with a bit more explanation:

```c
    /* The list is temporarily made empty, so that mutations performed
     * by comparison functions can't affect the slice of memory we're
     * sorting (allowing mutations during sorting is a core-dump
     * factory, since ob_item may change).
     */
```

The explanation isn't straight-forward but the problem is that the key-function and the comparisons could change the `list` instance during sorting which is very likely to result in undefined behavior of the C-code (which may crash the interpreter). To prevent that the list is emptied during the sorting, so that even if someone changes the instance it won't result in an interpreter crash.

This doesn't happen with `sorted` because `sorted` [copies the list](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2245) and [simply sorts the copy](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2249-L2261). The copy is still emptied during the sorting but there's no way to access it, so it isn't visible.

---

However you really shouldn't sort like this to get a frequency sort. That's because for each item you call the `key` function once. And `list.count` iterates over each item, so you effectively iterate the whole list for each element (what is called `O(n**2)` complexity). A better way would be to calculate the frequency once for each element (can be done in `O(n)`) and then just access that in the `key`.

However since CPython has a `Counter` class that also supports `most_common` you could really just use that:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [item for item, count in reversed(Counter(a).most_common()) for _ in range(count)]
[1, 2, 2, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4]
```

This may change the order of the elements with equal counts but since you're doing a frequency count that shouldn't matter to much.

Comment: Thanks for digging into the source code and confirming that the list being made empty is an implementation detail, it really is hard to find the answer but it usually is there.

Comment: @cs95 Interestingly it's also mentioned in the Python docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort). But it took me longer to find that than to find the comment in the source code ‍♂️